# What is a polynomial multiple?

Tags: polynomials

This is probably a really simple thing, but I am unable to find a definition.
I tried the internet and various textbooks.
This arose from Axler's Linear Algebra done right 3rd. Example 3.103
He says that U is a subspace consisting of all polynomial multiples of x^2.
What are all polynomial multiples of x^2?
But also in general what is a polynomial multiple?
Thank you

Comment: A "polynomial multiple of $x^2$" means $x^2$ times a polynomial. For example, $3x^5-x^4+2x^2$ is a polynomial multiple of $x^2$ since it's equal to $x^2(3x^3-x^2+2)$.

Answer (score 8):

An integer multiple of $2$ is any integer times $2$, so any integer of the form $2m$ for some integer $m$. In this case, that just means an even integer.

In the general case, an integer multiple of $n$ is any integer times $n$, so any integer of the form $nm$ for some other integer $m$.

A polynomial multiple of $x^2$ is any polynomial times $x^2$, i.e. $x^2 \cdot q(x)$ for any polynomial $q(x)$. For this example, that just means a polynomial such that its constant coefficient and its degree 1 coefficient both equal zero.

In the general case, given any polynomial $p(x)$, a polynomial multiple of $p(x)$ means any polynomial that can be factored in the form $p(x) q(x)$ for some other polynomial $q(x)$.